# How to locate plugins and dependencies that were used when a script was created? Nativescript

Tags: android, plugins, dependencies, nativescript, preview

Im working on a script that was developed in NativeScript. I am using "Playgound" and "Preview" for android with NativeScript. I have not been able to get the app to run, i believe there are additional plugins or dependencies in the original code, that i have not installed. Is there a way to determine what plugins or dependencies were used by the original developer? I have asked the developer, but due to corona virus they are unavailable, as an essential employee they are incommunicato! Thank You!

Comment: First of all, Preview is not best way if you are developing app involves many plugins. Preview app is built with a limited number of essential plugins like GPS, Camera etc., if you want to use any other plugins you must build the app locally. And `package.json` always tells you what are the dependencies.

Comment: thank you for the response. i have android studio, and visual studio, and a few other ide's. the developer created it with nativescript, so i was looking into that suite. Thanks again for the response, i will peruse the package.json.